# Problem sending file in POST request to API using Axios from a Firebase Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm using form-data and Axios to upload a file to another API from a Firebase Function. However, when I add `createReadStream(filePath)` to my `formData` object and attach it to my `POST` request, the response gives a `400` status code, claiming that the file is not present. My code:

```
const { fileName } = data;
const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'image.jpg');
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

await bucket.file(fileName).download({destination: tempFilePath});
   
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('photo', fs.createReadStream(tempFilePath));

const formHeaders = formData.getHeaders();

await axios.post('api/endpoint', formData, {
    headers: {
      ...formHeaders
    }
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error(err.response.data)
  });
```

The error I get after the Post request has a status code of `400` and is as follows:

```
{ error: 'invalid_query_missing_photo', ok: false }
```

I have verified that the `tempFilePath` does lead to an actual file, and **I am able to make the request from Postman.** However, even the code generated from Postman's code generation feature results in the same error.

My import statements:

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const axios = require('axios');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');
const { firebaseConfig } = require('firebase-functions');
const FormData = require('form-data');
```

Answer (score 0):

The error 400 is coming from the second API, maybe something else is required to mark an take the request as valid, or the field required is not named `photo`.

I tested your code and I created another function simulating the second API, in my second API, I experienced an HTTP error `400` when the file field of the form doesn't match with the required in the API

Second API Code (Function written on python)

```
import os

def hello_world(request):
        print(request.files)

        #this must match with the form field or you gonna receive an error 400
        file = request.files['photo'] 
        filename="cool.png"
        file.save(os.path.join("/tmp", filename))

        #this is to verify that the object were saved and is in /tmp
        print('Size         :', os.path.getsize(os.path.join("/tmp", filename)))

        return f'Hello World!'
```

With this second function I can validate that the issue is not coming from your function code.

Comment: I know the error is coming from the API I am calling, however I know for a fact that the error is claiming the photo is missing. It gives a status code 400 along with this specific error: { error: 'invalid_query_missing_photo', ok: false }

I am able to call the API via Postman with no more params than I am using in my code, but even the Postman generated code for an Axios environment ends with the same error. It has to be how the photo is being uploaded. I will triple check that I am using the correct params but since it is working from Postman (but not with JS code), I am deeply confused.

Comment: Maybe it could also be since I am running it from a Firebase Function somehow? That seems to be the only change, and may explain why the NodeJS/Axios Postman-generated code is not working, but I am not sure why running it from a Firebase Function that uses a Node environment would cause this kind of operation not to work.

Comment: @BryceChampaign Without more information from the another API is not possible offer more help, this doesn't look an issue caused by the cloud. is your node application running well on a local node.js server?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered you need to use getRawBody from the createReadStream, but only for cloud functions. This is what finally worked for me for google cloud firebase functions:

```
const fullFile = await getRawBody(fs.createReadStream(fileLocation));

    ...

formData.append('file', fullFile, { filename: 'somename.png'} );

    ...

await axios.post('api/endpoint', formData.getBuffer(), {
  headers: {
    ...formHeaders
  }
}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err.response.data)
});
```

This solved my error of:

```
 TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "string" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer. Received type object
```

Locally readstream seems to be converted into a full buffer automatically, but on cloud servers you need to convert it manually. There doesn't seem to be any documentation about this anywhere.